# Maven not downloading dependency from custom repository

Tags: maven, github

I'm trying to share some code between two projects by loading it as a dependency via maven. For some reason, I can't get Maven to pick up the dependency.

Here's how I generated the shared JAR:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/usr1/shared-code-1.0.0.jar -DpomFile=/Users/usr1/shared-code/pom.xml -DlocalRepositoryPath=.
```

This jar is held in a git repo `github.com/myOrg/myRepo/repository` where `repository` is the branch. The configuration described in the pom file for the shared code looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.myOrg</groupId>
<artifactId>shared-code</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Here's how I defined the dependency and repository in my other code bases:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myOrg</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-code</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    ...
    ...

    <repository>
        <id>shared-code/id>
        <name>Shared code for my stuff</name>
        <url>http://raw.github.com/myOrg/myRepo/repository</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>\
```

The exact error I'm getting when I try and do a `mvn clean package` is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project otherCodeBase: Could not resolve dependencies for project otherCode:myProject:jar:latest: Failure to find com.myOrg:shared-code:jar:1.0.0 in http://[company's artifactory repo] was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of artifactory has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

At first glance, it looks like Maven isn't even scanning the repository I defined in my other code's pom file, but when I execute `mvn help:effective-pom` it does appear. I should also add that I did make this repository public for the sake of getting it to work once. What gives?